# Finding the distance between a plane and $(0,0,0)$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Given the lines:

$ \frac{x+1}{4} = \frac{y-3}{1} = \frac{z}{k} $

and  $\frac{x-1}{3} = \frac{y+2}{-2} = \frac{z}{1} $

that lie on the same plane.

How can I find the parameter $k$ ?

(I guess I'll be able to calculate the distance between the resulting plane and (0,0,0) )

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Determining $k$

So you have these lines:

$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}
+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\k\end{pmatrix}
\;\middle\vert\;\lambda\in\mathbb R
\right\}
\qquad
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}
+\mu\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}
\;\middle\vert\;\mu\in\mathbb R
\right\}
$$

If you set $\lambda,\mu\in\{0,1\}$, you get these four points, two from each line:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\k\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}4\\-4\\1\end{pmatrix}\qquad
$$

Now if the two lines lie in a common plane, then so do these four points. Which you can check by computing a $4\times4$ determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & -2 & -4 \\
0 & k & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=22-11k=11(2-k)$$

The four points will be coplanar iff the determinant is zero, which is the case iff $k=2$.

## Computing the distance

Contrary to your suggested approach, the above approach does not at any point explicitely compute the distance of a given plane from the origin. If there were some other reason to compute that distance, then you'd do so by first computing two vectors whose direction lies within the plane. That would be the direction of one of the lines, and the difference between a pair of two points from different lines.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}-
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-2\\5\\0\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then you'd compute their cross product, which is a vector that is perpendicular to the plane:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}-2\\5\\0\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\\-11\end{pmatrix}
=: n
$$

Next you compute the dot product between this and one point on the plane, then divide by the norm of the above normal vector $n$:

$$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\\-11\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}}
{\sqrt{\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\\-11\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\\-11\end{pmatrix}}} =
\frac{-5+6}{\sqrt{25+4+121}}=\frac{1}{5\sqrt6}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But , how did you get the $4\times 4 $  determinant ? The last row is $(1,1,1,1)$ , where did you get it ? Thanks !

Comment: @homogenity: I know that from projective geometry. Adding a one to the coordinate vector turns it into homogeneous coordinates – very fitting for your user name. You can also interpret this determinant as six times the oriented [volume of the simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume) spanned by these four points. The volume will be zero if the points are coplanar.

Comment: IS there any simple way to see this without facts from projective geometry? I want to put this exercise as an exercise for calculus students :)

Comment: @homogenity: Sure. Take the three direction vectors $(-2,5,0), (3,-2,1)$ and $(4,1,k)$. The cross product between two of these (my $n$) is perpendicular to the plane. The third will be perpendicular to $n$ (and therefore in the same plane) if the dot product between it and $n$ are zero.

Comment: @homogenity: Or perhaps even more appropriate: the above three vectors have to lie in one plane, i.e. one two-dimensional linear subspace, so they have to be linearily dependent. Your students should be able to check for that.

Comment: And there is an appropriate reasoning for the $(1,1,1,1)$ without using projective geometry? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @homogenity: Because it yields the correct result… ;-) Seriously, take the determinant and subtract one column from all the others. Then you can develop the determinant on that sole remaining $1$ in the last row, and will in effect compute a $3\times3$ determinant where each 3-element vector is the difference between two of the original points.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot !